# Is there any way to implement compareTo method which would compare any supplied argument?

Tags: java, generics, compareto

The compiler says " cannot find symbol: method compareTo(java.lang.Object) ". Could you please advice where is the mistake here?

Here is the part of the code:

```
public class OBTComparable<ObjectType> implements Comparable<OBTComparable>
{
    public OTBComparable leftNode = null;
    public OBTComparable mainNode = null;
    public OBTComparable rightNode = null;
    public ObjectType object = null;

    public OBTComparable(ObjectType requiredObject)
    {
        object = requiredObject;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OBTComparable other)
    {
        if(object.compareTo(other.object) == 0)
            return 0;
        else 
            if (object.compareTo(other.object) > 0)
                return 1;
            else return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to scope `ObjectType` to `Comparable` too, because `OBTComparable` is [delegating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) `compareTo()` to `ObjectType`:

If you change `<ObjectType>` to  `<ObjectType extends Comparable<ObjectType>>`, it will compile:

```
public class OBTComparable<ObjectType extends Comparable<ObjectType>> implements Comparable<OBTComparable>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the proper code you are looking for (I replaced `ObjectType` with `T` for clarity):

```
class OBTComparable<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparable<OBTComparable<T>> {
    public OBTComparable<T> leftNode = null;
    public OBTComparable<T> mainNode = null;
    public OBTComparable<T> rightNode = null;
    public T object = null;

    public OBTComparable(T requiredObject) {
        object = requiredObject;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OBTComparable<T> other) {
        if (object.compareTo(other.object) == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (object.compareTo(other.object) > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else return -1;
    }
}
```

What did I change here:

1. OBTComparable uses a type parameter, so you should show it when you implement `Comparable`. Therefore you have `implements Comparable<OBTComparable<T>>` instead of simply `implements Comparable<OBTComparable>`.
2. You compare two objects in the `compareTo` method, but are they comparable? To make sure this requirement is fulfilled, you should write `OBTComparable<T extends Comparable<T>>` instead of just `OBTComparable<T>`. Then you will know that you can call `compareTo`.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: @newacct I agree, forgot about the PECS rule.

Answer (score 2):

ObjectType must also implement `Comparable<ObjectType>`.

And if you do this, I believe that this:

```
public int compareTo(OBTComparable other)
{
    if(object.compareTo(other.object) == 0)
        return 0;
    else 
        if (object.compareTo(other.object) > 0)
            return 1;
        else return -1;
}
```

can be simplified to this:

```
public int compareTo(OBTComparable other)
{
    return object.compareTo(other.object);
}
```